# VirtualBox shows only 32-bit options - tried all solns referenced

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, virtualbox, 64-bit

I have the following

1. Win 10 installed as 64-bit
2. Hyper-V is unchecked
3. BIOS setting enables Intel Virtualization

Is there a way to diagnose this 'common' problem beyond the suggestions?

The PC is pretty old (Lenovo B570).  Is it possible that this is a dead-end and I should just install 32-bit Ubuntu?

Comment: Since your PC is "pretty old" you may not be able to commit more than 4GB to your VM, so there is no point in installing 64-bit, except in two circumstances: (1) you want to develop 64-bit applications for Ubuntu; or (2) you anticipate copying the VM in the future to a machine with more memory.

Comment: Yeah... that's what I thought as well.  So I'm just downloading the 32-bit version of Ubuntu 16 LTS.